# LINQ Multiple table left join, distinct count not giving proper result

Tags: linq

I am sql query us producing correct result, but when i'm doing the same in LINQ. Output is incorrect. Please let me know where my making mistake.

Following linq query that i created.

LINQ Query:

```
List<UserModel> Model = (from users in db.UserM
                     join ct in db.CustT on users.UserId equals ct.UserID into group1
                     from g1 in group1.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     join ti in db.TestIn on  g1.TestId equals ti.TestID into group2
                     from g2 in group2.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     where (users.CustomerId==CustomerId) && (users.RoleId == 4) && (users.Status == 1)
                     group new
                     {
                         g2.TestInvitationID,
                         g2.TestID,
                     }
                     by new
                     {
                         users.FirstName,
                         users.CreatedOn,
                         users.Email,
                         users.UserId
                     } into group4

                     select new UserModel
                     {
                         Name =  group4.Key.FirstName,
                         CreatedOn = group4.Key.CreatedOn,
                         EmailId = group4.Key.Email,
                         UserId = group4.Key.UserId,
                         NoOfTestTaken = group4.Select(x=>x.TestID).Distinct().Count(),
                         NoOfInvitationsSent = group4.Count(x => x.TestInvitationID != 0)
                     }).ToList();
```

SQL Query:

```
SELECT IsNull(COUNT(distinct TS.TestId),0) AS NoOfTests,
       IsNull(COUNT(TS.TestInvitationID),0) AS NoOfInvitations,
       UM.Email,
       UM.UserId,
       UM.FirstName,
       UM.CreatedOn 
FROM UserM as UM  
left JOIN CustT AS CT 
ON UM.UserId=CT.UserId  
left JOIN TestIn AS TS 
ON TS.TestId = CT.TestId 

WHERE UM.CustomerId=41  
AND UM.RoleId=4 
and UM.[Status]=1 

GROUP BY UM.UserId, UM.Email, UM.FirstName, UM.CreatedOn
```

Tables:

- "UserM" - columns: UserId, Email, FirstName, CreatedOn
- "CustT" - columns: TestId,  UserId,
- "TestIn" - columns: TestInvitationId, TestId

Comment: that sql query is giving correct result soo......according to that reference plz answer

Comment: Please explain what you are getting that you weren't expecting. Some sample data and expected output will help too

Comment: My sql query is correct soo plz make it into linq

Comment: Is this LINQ to Entities? Please update the tags/post accordingly, i.e. Entity Framework, version etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between SQL `COUNT(expr)` and LINQ `Count` is that the former excludes `NULL` values, which produces a difference when used on right side of a left outer join with no matching records (SQL will produce `0` while LINQ `1`). The closest LINQ equivalent is `Count(expr != null)`.

So the direct translation of your SQL query would be like this (note that the generated SQL query could and most likely will be different):

*(A side note: When converting SQL query to LINQ, it's good to use the same aliases to make it easier to see the mappings)*

```
var query = 
    from um in db.UserMasters
    join ct in db.CustTests on um.UserId equals ct.UserID
    into ctGroup from ct in ctGroup.DefaultIfEmpty() // left outer join
    join ts in db.TestInvitaions on ct.TestId equals ts.TestID
    into tsGroup from ts in tsGroup.DefaultIfEmpty() // left outer join
    where um.CustomerId == UserSession.CustomerId
       && um.RoleId == 4
       && um.Status == 1
    group ts by new { um.UserId, um.Email, um.FirstName, um.CreatedOn } into g
    select new UserModel
    {
        Name =  g.Key.FirstName,
        CreatedOn = g.Key.CreatedOn,
        EmailId = g.Key.Email,
        UserId = g.Key.UserId,
        NoOfTestTaken = g.Where(ts => ts != null).Select(ts => ts.TestID).Distinct().Count(),
        NoOfInvitationsSent = g.Count(ts => ts != null)
     };

var result = query.ToList();
```

Comment: Oh nice, forgot about that with count on a null left join :) Good one

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the following row is the problem because is not the same like in your sql:

- Linq:

  ```
  NoOfInvitationsSent = group4.Count(x => x.TestInvitationID != 0)
  ```
- SQL:

  ```
  IsNull(COUNT(TS.TestInvitationID),0) AS NoOfInvitations
  ```
- Due to counting items from a left join Linq should be instead:

  ```
  NoOfInvitationsSent = group4.Where(i => i != null).Count()
  ```

To put it all together, with a bit of better formatting:

```
var model = (from users in db.UserMasters
             join ct in db.CustTests on users.UserId equals ct.UserID into group1
             from ct in group1.DefaultIfEmpty()
             join ti in db.TestInvitaions on  ct.TestId equals ti.TestID into group2
             from ct in group2.DefaultIfEmpty()

             where users.CustomerId == UserSession.CustomerId && 
                   users.RoleId == 4 && 
                   users.Status == 1

             group new { ct.TestInvitationID, ct.TestID }
             by new
             {
                 users.FirstName,
                 users.CreatedOn,
                 users.Email,
                 users.UserId
             } into grouping

             select new UserModel
             {
                 Name =  grouping.Key.FirstName,
                 CreatedOn = grouping.Key.CreatedOn,
                 EmailId = grouping.Key.Email,
                 UserId = grouping.Key.UserId,
                 NoOfTestTaken = grouping.Where(i => i != null).Select(x => x.TestID).Distinct().Count(),
                 NoOfInvitationsSent = grouping.Where(i => i != null).Count()
             }).ToList();
```

Comment: @Gaurry - then please, again, as requested above explain what is your data, what you are getting, what you are expecting. And when you say "not working" you must explain what that means...